# Merging Arrays in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I need to merge a collection of arrays based on id.

Example data:

EDIT: (changed to match Clojure data structures)

```
 [{:id 1, :region :NA, :name :Test1, :OS :W}
  {:id 1, :region :EU, :name :Test2, :OS :W}
  {:id 2, :region :AS, :name :test3, :OS :L}
  {:id 2, :region :AS, :name :test4, :OS :M}]
```

Becomes:

EDIT: (changed to match Clojure data structures)

```
[{:id 1, :region [:NA :EU], :name [:Test1 :Test2] ,:OS [:W]}
 {:id 2, :region [:AS] :name [:test3 :Test4], :OS [:L :M]}]
```

| is the delimiter (changeable)
If possible, also would like alphabetical order as well.

Comment: These are not valid Clojure data structures. Are these strings? Is this a question about string parsing/manipulation in Clojure? What have you tried so far to solve this problem? Please provide examples of code. In this form it's not a good question.

Comment: the intent of the first part is fairly clear, so I edited the structures. I'm not sure how to interpret the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(def data
 [{:id 1, :region :NA, :name :Test1, :OS :W}
  {:id 1, :region :EU, :name :Test2, :OS :W}
  {:id 2, :region :AS, :name :test3, :OS :L}
  {:id 2, :region :AS, :name :test4, :OS :M}])

(defn key-join
  "join of map by key , value is distinct."
  [map-list]
  (let [keys (keys (first map-list))]
       (into {} (for [k keys] [k (vec (set (map #(% k) map-list)))]))))

(defn group-reduce [key map-list]
  (let [gdata (group-by key map-list)]
    (into [] (for [[k m] gdata] (let [m (key-join m)](assoc m key ((key m) 0)))))))



user=> (group-reduce :id data)
[{:name [:Test2 :Test1], :OS [:W], :region [:EU :NA], :id 1} {:name [:test3 :test4], :OS [:L :M], :region [:AS], :id 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some combination of functions from `clojure.set` (if you change the outermost vector to set). Specifically [`clojure.set/index`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.set/index) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `merge-with` function as shown below in the example.

Firstly, we define some helper functions

```
(defn collect [& xs]
  (apply vector (-> xs distinct sort)))
```

The `collect` function makes sure that the items in `xs` are unique and sorted and finally returns them in a vector.

```
(defn merge-keys [k xs]
  (map #(apply merge-with collect %) (vals (group-by k xs))))
```

`merge-keys` first groups the hash-maps in `xs` by a primary key (in your case `:id`), takes each list of grouped items and merges the values of the keys using the `collect` function from above.

```
(def xs [{:id 1, :region :NA, :name :Test1, :OS :W}
         {:id 1, :region :EU, :name :Test2, :OS :W}
         {:id 2, :region :AS, :name :test3, :OS :L}
         {:id 2, :region :AS, :name :test4, :OS :M}])

(merge-keys :id xs)
=> ({:id [1],
     :region [:EU :NA],
     :name [:Test1 :Test2],
     :OS [:W]}
    {:id [2],
     :region [:AS],
     :name [:test3 :test4],
     :OS [:L :M]})
```

**Note** however that even the `:id` key now has vector associated with it. You can easily *un-vector* it by either introducing an `if` statement in `collect` which associates a single value with the key instead of a vector...

```
(defn collect [& xs]
  (let [cs (apply vector (-> xs distinct sort))]
    (if (= 1 (count cs)) (first cs) cs)))
```

...or take the result from `merge-keys` and do

```
(map #(update-in % [:id] first) result)
```

which will only *un-vector* the `:id` map entry